# Show that if $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$ is super-increasing sequence, then $2^{j-1}\leq a_j$ for $j=1,...,n$

Tags: number-theory, induction

**I tried by induction:**

1) For $j=1$: $2^0=1 \leq a_1 $ --> ok!

2) Say it's true for $j=k$ then $2^{k-1}\leq a_k $

3) Proof that: $j=k+1$ then $2^{k}\leq a_{k+1} $

**And now I don't know how to proof this! Are there two types of induction?**

The solution is given by:
[image]

[image]

Comment: It is al so called [strong induction](http://www.oxfordmathcenter.com/drupal7/node/485)

Comment: @Bumblebee OK, but how does this work for this example? We already have an ≤ to proof.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention the definition of "super-increasing", but from the above "proof", one can understand that we are speaking of a sequence of positive integers $a_k$ satisfying the inequality $$a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_{k-1}\le a_k\tag1$$ for $k>1$. The sequence defined by $a_1=1$ and $a_k=2^{k-2}$ for $k\ge2$ is super-increasing, with equality in (1), but $2^{k-2}\ge2^{k-1}$ is wrong, of course. The mistake in the proof is that the author shows $a_k\ge2^{k-1}-1$, and draws the conclusion that $a_k\ge2^k$, that's a typo for $a_k\ge2^{k-1}$, but even that conclusion would be wrong.
One could prove $a_k\ge2^{k-2}$ in the general case, but you don't need strong induction for that.