# Show that if $ b_1, b_2, …, b_n $ is a superincreasing sequence then $ b_{i+j} \gt 2^{j-1} b_i $ for $ 1 \leq i \leq n $ and $ 1 \leq j $.

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, induction

Superincreasing sequence definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superincreasing_sequence.

I tried converting $ b_{i+j} $ using property from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2573314/show-that-if-a-1-a-2-a-n-is-super-increasing-sequence-then-2j-1-le), but didn't get anywhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So $b_{i+j}>b_{i+j-1}+\cdots +b_{i}+b_{i-1}+\cdots +b_1$ but $b_{i+j-1}>b_{i+j-2}+\cdots b_i+\cdots +b_1,$ hence
$$b_{i+j}>(b_{i+j-2}+\cdots b_i+\cdots +b_1)+b_{i+j-2}+\cdots b_i+\cdots +b_1=2\left (b_{i+j-2}+\cdots b_i+\cdots +b_1\right ),$$
so doing this $j-1$ times...
$$b_{i+j}>2\left (b_{i+j-2}+\cdots +b_i+\cdots +b_1\right )>2\left (2\left (b_{i+j-3}+\cdots +b_i+\cdots +b_1\right )\right )>\cdots >2^{j-1}\left (b_i+\cdots+ b_1\right ),$$
but the $b_j$ are positive reals, so $b_j>0$ hence put everyone to $0$ except $b_i$ then
$$b_{i+j}>2^{j-1}\left (b_i+0+\cdots +0\right)=2^{j-1}b_i.$$